# Getters and Setters - How does "value" work, particularly in an if statement?

Tags: c#, oop, getter-setter

I've been working through this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhQdlIFylQ8&t=11038s

I am working through "Getters & Setters" at 3:54:60 (other subjects for C# are in the description for any needed context).

This is a class that I've made in order to print to the Console as well as a "Getter and Setter".

```
class Song
{
    private string title;
    public string artist;
    public int duration;

    public Song(string aTitle, string aArtist, int aDuration)
    {
        title = aTitle;
        artist = aArtist;
        duration = aDuration;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set {
            if (value == "Hello")
            {
                value = "ERROR";

            } else
            {
                title = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the "Main" sort of code to print out the titles of two `Song` objects: "hello" and "kashmir".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Song hello = new Song("Hello", "Adele", 400);
        Song kashmir = new Song("Kashmir", "Green Day", 200);

        Console.WriteLine(hello.Title);
        Console.WriteLine(kashmir.Title);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

However, I've tried to experiment with the "Getters and Setters" by seeing how I could print out something other than the song titles.

When I run the program, it prints out **`Hello`** and **`Kashmir`** both on separate lines.

How do I get it to print **`ERROR`** or something other than the song titles (or what other ways could I do this)?

Comment: When you assign a value to a property, like `Title = "Ice cream";` then the setter of that property is being called. The special `value` variable in property setters contain the value that is being assigned to the property (which in my example case is `"Ice cream"`). Your program not printing out "ERROR" has nothing to do with the nature of that special `value` variable. Rather look very carefully what your `if` statement does there in the property setter while taking into account what the property getter is actually doing. Also pay attention to when the setter is being called and when not...

Comment: You have a simple logic error. Learn to use the debugger early in your studies.

Comment: The logic error is that, in the class constructor, you're setting the backing field. The value check is done by the Property setter. Setting the backing field won't trigger the validation in the setter. Assign the values passed in the costructor directly to the properties so the condition will be evaluated. Don't try to change the `value` content, set the filed(s) with the validated value instead. You could also ditch the backing filed an use auto-properties, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sorta funny thing going on here that even seasoned devs occasionally trip over...and it's missing the difference between a backing field and a property. This happens from time to time...and absolutely baffles the dev until they realize they've made a Visual Studio intellisense-assisted error. It's doubly likely if you name your backing field the same as the property name...differing only in case.

```
class Song
{
    private string title;  //--> this is the "backing field" for the property "Title"
    public string artist;
    public int duration;

    public Song(string aTitle, string aArtist, int aDuration)
    {
        //title = aTitle; //--> this only sets the backing field...not the "Title" property
        Title = aTitle;  //--> this sets your "Title" property
        artist = aArtist;
        duration = aDuration;
    }
```

The next issue is that, in a property `set`, the `value` is the *incoming* suggested value for the property. You don't have to accept it. Your job in the property `set` is to validate the incoming value, and put it into the backing field if you like it...or *maybe* put something else in if you don't. Changing the incoming `value` is rarely what you want to do. You almost got it right...here's the commented fix:

```
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }

        set {
            if (value == "Hello")
            {
                //value = "ERROR"; //--> this only changes the incoming value
                title = "ERROR";   //--> this sets your backing field

            } else
            {
                title = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Having said all that, it's not at all uncommon to see the constructor set only backing fields, rather than going through the sometimes-expensive validating code of the property `set`. A lot of times, the property is the *public* API for the users of your type to set the value...while the constructor is kept internal or private and is only used to fill in values that had been saved off somewhere..like in a database. A good idea? Maybe/maybe not. As you've just discovered, bypassing the property `set` can leave you with something that might be an error.

Comment: Just to make sure I am getting the right idea, I am gonna talk about what I think my problems are and if I am wrong in any way, I'd be grateful if you or anybody let me know. 
One of my problems was the fact that I had set the backing field required for the property `Title` but I haven't actually `set` the property itself in order for it to print out to the Console. My next problem was that I used `value` in an unnecessary way, learning from your answer that changing the incoming `value` is something I wouldn't normally want to do.

Comment: Right - setting Title runs your Title setter...which in turns sets the title backing field. And yes...setting the `value` is almost never appropriate. Usually you'll just put it into your backing field. Note, there may be times where you compare the current backing field to the `value` to decide what to do...but it sounds like you're getting there!

Answer (score 0):

You should not assign "Error" to Value keyword.

Value keyword is to hold the input.  This is useful if you want to perform validations before assigning values to the field.  If you assign something to Value it will not be hold by the class.

EDIT - 
As mentioned in below comment - your code is *not using the property setter* but it is *setting values through the constructor*.

You have two options -

Option 1 - Add same validations in constructor.
Option 2 - In constructor set properties instead of fields

Option 2 makes more sense to me as it avoids the code duplication.

You will have to make small change in title proprty

```
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }

        set {
            if (value == "Hello")
            {
                title = "ERROR";

            } else
            {
                title = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The OP claims it compiles and runs. I honestly never tried to assign to it.

Comment: While you explanation so far is correct, it does not fully solve the problem. Note that the code in the question actually does no property assignment, hence the setter is never being called...